# PCA, LDA and Naive Baysian

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to apply Linear Discriminant Analysis to a two-class problem. As far as I understand, LDA assumes that both classes have the same covariance matrix, and then models the likelihood as Gaussian distribution with different means.

Another classifier that I have tried is the naive Bayesian. It disregards any correlation between predictor variables.

Now, I don't understand what happens when I apply PCA to the dataset. By its very definition, the PCA algorithm rotates the data such that the covariance matrix is diagonal. Nothing is lost in the rotation, but since the covariance matrix is now diagonal, shouldn’t the naive Bayesian be just as good as LDA, or even better, since the LDA will have many more parameters to estimate? Yet, on my data, the Naive Bayes is outperformed by LDA with or without PCA.

Indeed, the data is exactly the same as long as I use all the principal components, which tells me that the result should indeed be as it is. Yet the covariance matrix is diagonal... *brain meltdown*

Can somebody explain this to me? I hope that I have phrased my question clearly enough. Thank you!

Comment: try asking that on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: but how are you using PCA for classification ? this is method of dimension reduction/scaling

Comment: Well, I am in fact doing classification. I ran into problems when using QDA, because the covariance matrix wasn't invertible (not full rank). I used PCA to reduce the dimensionality enough so that the covariance matrix became full rank. Then I started wondering about the naive Bayes, which led me to post this question :)

Answer (score 6):

PCA is useful for dimensionality reduction (e.g., if the size of your training set is too small for the number of dimensions of the data).  But if you are using all of the principal components, PCA won't improve the results of your linear classifier - if your classes weren't linearly separable in the original data space, then rotating your coordinates via PCA won't change that.

The other point to note regarding PCA is that it is calculates the coordinate rotation based on statistics of the *entire* set of samples, without regard to class labels.  Even though your classes may be perfectly linearly separable (both before and after PCA), that doesn't imply that they will be separable independently by each of your transformed coordinates (i.e., the linear decision boundary isn't parallel to any of your transformed coordinate axes).  In that type of situation, I would expect Naive Bayes to yield lower accuracy since, by definition, it treats each axis independently.

Comment: Very good point. the second paragraph exactly explains what I did wrong :). Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, PCA by itself does not eliminate the dependencies between the variables, just finds a reparameterization of  the data. If you then discarded all but a few top-variance dimensions (which is known as dimensionality reduction), this might help. I think, however, that in a setting with only two classes and many interdependent features using a discriminative classifier might work better that PCA+bayes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Yes, I'm pretty sure that you're right about the PCA not changing the data as such, but then I'm not sure what's happening. After all, if I calculate the covariance matrix on the rotated data, I get a diagonal matrix, which seems like the ideal conditions for naive Bayes. So my thinking must be mistaken somewhere, yet I can't see where...

Comment: @onkel could it be that you mix up *linear independence* in the algebraic sense and *conditional independence* in the probabilistic sense? I don't think PCA makes the variables independent in the latter sense.

Comment: @onkel also, there's a general discussion about PCA here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues and some useful links

Comment: You're right, I did forget about conditional independence! I think that I worked it out. I would like to post my own explanation to myself as an answer, but I can't seem to be able to (sorry, new to this site :). Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Qnan, could you say a bit more about this distinction between conditional and linear independence? After all, PCA uses the covariance matrix, which measures conditional dependence. So in this particular case, wouldn't eliminating linear dependencies also eliminate (linear) conditional dependencies? Of course there might be nonlinear dependencies that PCA might miss (as illustrated by the first diagram in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) article). But the point remains -- in some cases PCA _will_ eliminate conditional dependencies. Or is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@bogatron Just to point out that Naive Bayes does not require the problem is linearly separable in one of the dimensions. In a two-class problem in a 3-d space, the decision boundary is on

```
p(x|1)p(y|1)p(z|1) = p(x|2)p(y|2)p(z|2)
```

if we assume a uniform hypothesis prior that

```
P(M1)=P(M2)=0.5.
```

Depending on the specific forms of `p(.|1) and p(.|2)`, the boundary could be complex and nonlinear, and not parallel to any axis.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that Naive Bayes *requires* the classes to be linearly separable in one dimension. The issue relevant to the question is that when they are not, Naive Bayes can yield significantly lower accuracy due to its assumption of conditional independence and one can easily construct cases that demonstrate this.